# How to merge DFs by date, using only day and month, using specified date range

Tags: pandas, merge, time-series, helper

I have a DF (df0) with a range of dates:

```
date
12/30/2018
12/31/2018
1/1/2019
1/2/2019
1/3/2019
```

And a DF (df1) with data:

```
date        loc temp
12/30/2017  YYC 5.07
12/31/2017  YYC 5.64
1/1/2017    YYC 3.43
1/2/2017    YYC 7.89
1/3/2017    YYC 2.49
12/30/2017  YYZ 4.08
12/31/2017  YYZ 7.40
1/1/2017    YYZ 7.82
1/2/2017    YYZ 8.33
1/3/2017    YYZ 7.74
```

I would like to create a new df by merging the info in df1 onto the date range in df0 using **only the day and month** in df1.  It would not matter if the years do not match up.  IE: 12/30/2018 would take the data from 12/30/2017 in df1.

The date range in df0 is the key date range which I would like to keep.

There only one temp value per loc for each day in a calendar year.  That same value could appear multiple times if df0 spanned multiple years. IE: if df0 were a ten years long time series, I would see YYC = 5.07 ten times, on each 12/30 of the time series.

In the example of df0 and df1 above, the new data frame (df2) would have two entries for 12/30/2018:

```
date        loc temp
12/30/2018  YYC 5.07
12/30/2018  YYZ 4.08
```

I don't believe I can .merge these, as its on date.  I don't believe I can do .isin df0, as I need to match only a portion (day and month)

Comment: Your output seems wrong. `date` is from df1  but the values are from df0 which has the column `Date`

Comment: I edited the post - date was capitalized in error.  You are correct, it is the dates in df0 which I wish to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each dataframe create a month and day column and then merge df1 with df0:

```
import pandas as pd

df0['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['Date'])
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df0['day'] = df0.Date.dt.day
df0['month'] = df0.Date.dt.month
df1['day'] = df1.date.dt.day
df1['month'] = df1.date.dt.month

df0.merge(df1, how='inner', on=['month', 'day']).drop(columns=['month', 'day', 'date'])

    Date    loc temp
0   2018-12-30  YYC 5.07
1   2018-12-30  YYZ 4.08
2   2018-12-31  YYC 5.64
3   2018-12-31  YYZ 7.4
4   2019-01-01  YYC 3.43
5   2019-01-01  YYZ 7.82
6   2019-01-02  YYC 7.89
7   2019-01-02  YYZ 8.33
8   2019-01-03  YYC 2.49
9   2019-01-03  YYZ 7.74
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I had been thinking helpers might be required, but hoped there was another option.  For `.drop(columns=)` I am getting a   **.drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'** error.  I changed to  `.drop(['month','day'],1)` and it appears to be working fine.  Do you know if this is a change in the syntax between versions?

Comment: Also one question - I saw your comment above about Date/date, and I changed so those headers match.  After merging, that results in two date columns: date_x and date_y.  Any tips on dropping the correct date?  I thought about dropping it while preparing the helper columns.  Or can drop it directly via date_correct letter, but I wasn't sure as to the automatic naming conventions of pandas.

Comment: so you get `date_x` and `date_y` when both DataFrames have a column with the same name that is not in the merge key.  That way you can distinguish which DataFrame those variables came from. I'd suggest just keeping one named `Date` and the other named `date` that way you can just drop whichever one you don't want in the end, without worrying about renaming.

Comment: and yes, it seems the argument `columns` was added in 0.21.0.